# ToFile block mat file format

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have set my Matlab (R2019b Update 9) to save Mat files in version 7 because I have a Python script that uses the scipy.io module to load mat files and v7.3 format is not supported by this Python module.
Manually saved mat files from Matlab workspace variables are created in format v7, however mat files created from Simulink ToFile blocks seem not to use that format as when I run my script on such mat files I encounter the error below:

> NotImplementedError: Please use HDF reader for matlab v7.3 files

How to enforce ToFile blocks to use v7 format?

Comment: Write a MATLAB script to read back Simulink file and save to '-v7'? It could be slow but still way faster than waiting for MATLAB update...

Comment: Thanks, that's indeed an easy fix. My concern was whether I was missing something but after a careful read of the documentation I found that "To avoid the overhead of compressing data in real time, the To File block writes an uncompressed Version 7.3 MAT-file. " So it seems it is not a bug but a feature.

Comment: Actually mat v7.3 is just packaged HDF5. IDK your detailed data structure but there's a chance that read the file with HDF5 libs in python be easier than the back-and-forth dance in matlab.

Comment: Thanks again. Your right, I ended up reading it with h5py with almost no modification to the previous code.